# Need to export the output to CSV File

Tags: powershell

I have script to get the active users in Remote desktop servers. So i want the output to be saved in excel file. Here the script & actual output. In that output i need to add the $host variable data in first column of the excel.

```
$Comp = Get-Content D:\Hosss.txt
 foreach ($hosts in $comp) {
 $resul = quser /server:$hosts 
 $resul | Export-Csv d:\active.csv -Append
}
```

[image: Actual output]

Comment: The main issue is that the output of quser is plain text and not an "object" that can be easily manipulated.
The idea is to parse the output of the quser command and transform the plain text into objects.
Then you can add any property you would like with Add-Member, adding by example the host.
You can find a script [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4408-get-logged-in-users-remote-computers-or-local) that transform the plain text output of quser into objects.

Comment: @Hazrelle Thanks for Help. Its working perfectly what is I am expected.